# What does the dot operator `.` (before the generic parameter) mean?

Tags: java, generics, syntax, guava

I saw this code today:

```
    ImmutableMap<Class<? extends ClientCommand>, CommandProcessorInterface> immutableMap =
            ImmutableMap.<Class<? extends  ClientCommand>, CommandProcessorInterface>of(...
```

What does this syntax mean?

`ImmutableMap.<Class ..`

I knew generics was right after the class name. No?

What is the difference between:

`ImmutableMap<Class..` and `ImmutableMap.<Class..`

Comment: It's generic parameters for static method `of`, not for class itself.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It means you're invoking a generic static method, called `of` in the `ImmutableMap` class.

It's pretty much the same as you're invoking a `static` method, nested in some class:

```
SomeClass.staticMethod();
```

For the cases when your method has a type-parameter defined, you can explicitly provide the generic type and this is done like this:

```
SomeClass.<Type>genericStaticMethod();
```

And to answer you final question:

> What is the difference between `ImmutableMap<Class...>` and `ImmutableMap.<Class...` ?

The first is usually used when creating an instance of a generic class. It's used to define the  generic-type on class level, while the second is used to invoke a generic static method that's nested in some class.

Comment: You don't usually need to provide it. See the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). `fromArrayToCollection(sa, cs); // T inferred to be String`

Comment: It might be deduced from the return type cast (or assignation) but it is not always possible. I just say "_you need to provide the generic type_" it is not always true

Comment: @user270349 I would go so far as to say that the statement "you need to" is simply wrong.

Answer (score 12):

It concerns a static method `ImmutableMap.of`. This has its own generic type parameters.

```
class Test {

static <T> T f() { return null; }

void t() {
    String s = Test.f();                 // Inferred from LHS.
    String t = Test.<String>f();         // Not needed.
    int n = Test.<String>f().length();   // Needed.
}
```

In your case it seems not really needed, but there I am on thin ice, as the generic type inference became a bit stronger in Java 8.

Answer (score 7):

Generic methods are methods declared with any generic type parameter.
See doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). The generic type of the method doesn't have to be related to any generic type parameter of the declaring class. The class may or may not be generic.

**When invoking a generic method (static or not) you may specify the generic type but you don't usually see it because it is usually autodetected. That syntax you found is the one to specify it.**

If there is a method declared like this:

```
<T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c) { ...
```

you may call it like this:

```
Integer[] a = ...
ArrayList<Integer> l = ...
x.fromArrayToCollection(a, l);
```

but if you have one like this:

```
<T> Collection<T> myMethod(int c) {
  return new ArrayList<T>(c);
}
```

Then you have two ways to clarify the type to the compiler. You can give it enough information in two ways.

One is specifying the type in the call:

```
Object c = x.<Integer>myMethod(5);
```

The other is with a typecast (explicit or implicit by assigning to a variable):

```
Collection<Integer> c = x.myMethod(5);
```

Comment: `Object c =` & explicit/implicit is what was missing in my answer. Upvote

Answer (score 2):

The complete invocation type for generic method is(as said by [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)):

```
// use Collections#emptyList as an example
List<String> a = Collections.<String>emptyList();
```

which can be simplified as:

```
// use Collections#emptyList as an example
List<String> a = Collections.emptyList();
```

And another example:

```
List<String> a = ...;
String s = a.<String>get(0);
```

The letter type parameter can also be simplified as:

```
String s = a.get(0);
```

This is called [Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).

See several examples for Guava `ImmutableMap`:

```
// type parameter can be omitted
ImmutableMap<String, Integer> map = ImmutableMap.<String, Integer>of("a", 1);
```

can be simplified as:

```
ImmutableMap<String, Integer> map = ImmutableMap.of("a", 1);
```

this is inferred by target type.

But for this one:

```
// type parameter can not be omitted
ImmutableMap<String, Integer> map = ImmutableMap.<String, Integer>builder().build();
```

This is confusing. Indeed, the complete format is:

```
// the latter type parameter can be omitted
ImmutableMap<String, Integer> map = ImmutableMap.<String, Integer>builder().<String, Integer>build();
```

There are two consecutive generic methods: `builder` & `build`. For the latter method, type parameter can be omitted because of target type inference. For the former method, it's not the case. There is no target type for it to infer, so the type parameter must be wrritten here:

```
ImmutableMap<String, Integer> map = ImmutableMap.<String, Integer>builder()...
```

If you really wanna omit type parameter for both `builder` and `build`, they must both have target type for inferring:

```
ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Integer> builder = ImmutableMap.builder();
ImmutableMap<String, Integer> immutableMap = builder.build();
```