# Generics angle brackets before static function call

Tags: java, generics, static, guava

I have always used generics and always seen the angle brackets used like this: `Class<Type>` (e.g. `List<String>`).

Today I encountered a generics specification before the call of a static method like: `Class.<TypeA, TypeB>staticCall()`. The real example is: `ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()`.

I've never seen this usage and I can't find this specific usage in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). Can someone explain what is going on, please?

Comment: It's a generic static method, see the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166610/what-does-the-dot-operator-before-the-generic-parameter-mean

Comment: Oh, yes, this was what I was looking for! I didn't though about searching for the . operator instead of the generics after that. Maybe leave open for people that will search that in my same way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are called [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

Before Java 7 you had to specify the type of the Generic reference:

```
Util.<Integer, String>compare(p1, p2);
```

Now the compiler infers the type from the context.

Comment: Mmm, I am on Java 8 and still have to specify the Generic reference. :confused:

Comment: please read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).

Answer (score 0):

we can define generics on class level also .

ImmutableMap.Builder means Builder is inner static class here .

and Builder methods will have K and V as arguments means

means instead providing put(String , String) it provides methos like put(K,V) so that any type can be added using put and if you get you need use the same type.

for example if your are calling Builder.Put by passing string , String then in get we can directly assign to String

String val = Bullder.get(K);

it means all methods of ImmutableMap.Builder will work for any class type.

that is the  power of generics meaning no need to overlaod methods for different type.
 just define like below:

```
public Builder<K, V> put(K key, V value) {
  ensureCapacity(size + 1);
  ImmutableMapEntry<K, V> entry = entryOf(key, value);
  // don't inline this: we want to fail atomically if key or value is null
  entries[size++] = entry;
  return this;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's signifying multiple types.  List only takes one generic type which is why you see

```
List<String>
```

From the java docs for [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

At the top you'll see: 
Interface Map

so it takes two [generic types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). In the example of your Immutable map, it's saying that the K(ey) is a String and V(alue) is also a String.

In the link you provided, it mentions that this is possible under section,

> A Generic Version of the Box Class

Comment: Maybe I had to specify that, I know that you can specify 2 types. I didn't know that you can specify that before a method call. :)

Comment: I think you are typing the class you are calling the static method on - the Immutable Map class itself is specific to a typed key and value.  You always reference class name before calling static method, in this case class name just includes the generic type implementations.