# Sort list of strings by multiple parameters

Tags: java, sorting, lambda

I'm considering how to sort an ArrayList with two parameters. First by occurences of some char in string, then by natural order. Here is the code:

```
  ArrayList<String> words;
    words=getWords(sentence);//return all words from sentence
    words.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> countChar(c,  o))
                     .thenComparing(Comparator::naturalOrder));
```

Method `getWords(sentence)` return an `ArrayList<String>` of words from `sentence`.

Method `countChar(c,o)` counts number of char `c` in word `o`.

When adding `.thenComparing(Comparator::naturalOrder))` IDE shows that `o` should be cast to `String` and that it can't resolve method `thenComparing()`.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to Generate a thumbnail from a video url in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954894/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two mistakes in your code.

1. You'll need to provide the generic parameters to `comparing`
2. `naturalOrder` *returns* a comparator; invoke it, rather than passing a reference

Try:

```
        words.sort(Comparator.<String, Integer>comparing(o -> countChar(c,  o))
                         .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

Comment: It compiles fine. Could you please tell me why are we providing `Comparator.<>` than `Comparator<>.`. I am poor in generics :(

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166610/what-does-the-dot-operator-before-the-generic-parameter-mean

Comment: Great answer! Added `.reversed()` as elements with occurences of char `c` should go first and than elements in natural order:

 ```words.sort(Comparator.<String, Integer>comparing(o -> countChar(c,  o)).reversed().thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to add an object with count(c) and impl the Comparable.

```java
class StringWithChar implements Comparable<StringWithChar> {
    private String s;
    private char c;
    private long count;
    public StringWithChar(String s, char c) {
         this.s = s;
         this.c = c;
         count = s.chars().filter(ch -> ch == c).count();
     }

     public String getS() {
         return s;
     }

     public void setS(String s) {
         this.s = s;
     }

     public char getC() {
         return c;
     }

     public void setC(char c) {
         this.c = c;
     }

     public long getCount() {
         return count;
     }

     public void setCount(long count) {
         this.count = count;
     }

     @Override
     public int compareTo(StringWithChar s2) {
         int res = Long.compare(this.getCount(), s2.getCount());
         if (res == 0) {
             return this.getS().compareTo(s2.getS());
         }
         return res;
     }
 }

// then you can easier stream 
words.stream().map(s -> new StringWithChar(s, c)).sort().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: `class StringWithChar implements Comparator<StringWithChar>` are you possibly confusing [`Comparable` and `Comparator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266827/when-to-use-comparable-and-comparator/31244596)?

Answer (score 0):

My only concern with that approach is a potential performance bottle neck as it could potentially loop through all elements to sort by the first comparator then loop again to sort by the 2nd comparator.
Perhaps try creating a single comparator that does both comparisons and use that instead?

Comment: list will be sort by a single - combined - comparator. No need to worry about list being traversed twice...

Comment: This approach works, but I expected usage of Java 8 will make it look better :)
```words.sort((s1, s2) -> {

            int charCount;

            charCount = Integer.compare(countChar(c, s2), countChar(c, s1));

            if (charCount != 0) {

                return charCount;

            }
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        });```